# RxJS Node wait for observable to complete before subscribing to the next in sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I'm trying to populate my database with values scraped from a google sheet. hasuraHelper.insert() makes an HTTP post to my database. How do I make it so that an insert() will be called only after the previous api call returns? I thought a concatMap would do the trick but it seems like it still eagerly subscribes to all emissions.

Currently: Request 1 -> Request 2 -> ... -> Request 1 completes -> Request 2 completes -> ...

What I would like: Request 1 -> Request 1 completes -> Request 2 -> Request 2 completes -> ...

Here is the relevant code:

```
sheetsHelper.authToken()
    .flatMap(sheetsHelper.get)
    .flatMap(response => response.values) //values is a 2d array
    .map(row => {
        console.log(row[0]);
        const flights = [];
        //add 100-500 objects to this array
        return flights;
    })
    .flatMap(flights => {
        const arrayOfFlightArrays = [];
        //max batch size of 50
        while (flights.length) {
            const flightArr = flights.splice(0, 50);
            arrayOfFlightArrays.push(flightArr);
        }
        return Rx.Observable.from(arrayOfFlightArrays);
    })
    .concatMap(flights => hasuraHelper.insert(flights) //insert flights into table
        .retry()) 
    .map(response => response.data)
    .subscribe(console.log, console.error);
```

This is what the insert looks like:

```
exports.insert = function (objects) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/',
        data: {
            type: "insert",
            args: {
                table: "flights",
                objects: objects
            }
        }
    }));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your insert function is not lazy. You are wrapping a executing promise in an Observable but it is already executing.

To get a promise to become lazy and start processing when subscribed to you need to wrap it in `Rx.Observable.defer(() => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios(/* ... */))`

Comment: Hmm, so concatMap consumes emissions to create the observable as soon as it can but only subscribes to them once the previous one completes?

Comment: Correct! Most times that is not a problem because a common pattern is that  Observables are cold (=not doing things until subscribed to).